# How many will be elected in 2012?

Tags: support, election

How many Moderators will be elected this year?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the sidebar of [the election page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election), it says it:

> #### moderator positions available
>
> 2

Comment: Is there any replacement?

Comment: @Pierre303 The election is to fill Anna Lear's slot [now that she works for Stack Exchange](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2875/8).

Comment: ah yes I completely forgot the news ;)